# VIM How to insert output of a shell command at a different place in the file

Tags: vim

I have come up with a perl script that outputs a template for documenting functions and structures given the definition of a function/struct from my C code.

To use it , i visually select the definition of the struct, yank and paste it right above the original definition, and invoke the script on this pasted struct. It replaces it with document for that struct.

Now is there a way that will avoid that yank paste? I am looking for a way to invoke a shell command but the output from that should be pasted somewhere else in the file, not necessarily on top of it.

IOW 
:'a,'b!perl ~/bin/document.pl 
replaces text between mark a and markb, I want to *add* the output of document.pl above mark a.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to modify the perl script in a way that it also outputs its input at the end. Then you would end up with the desired result.

Comment: Yes I can do that but I want to keep that script clean. I can create another script only for VI. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you have zsh as your shell, you can use co-process:

```
'a,'b!coproc perl ~/bin/document.pl ; tee >&p | cat <&p
```

To get output before your text (this command puts it after), you should use a slightly more complex command:

```
'a,'b!coproc perl ~/bin/document.pl ; tee >&p | cat <(<&p) -
```

System-independent solution, using vim and temporary buffer:

```
'a,'byank a | new | 0put a | $d | execute "%!perl ~/bin/document.pl" | %d a | bw! | 'a-1put a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
function! MyFunc() range
  " Preserve the register.
  let old_reg = @a
  exec a:firstline.','.a:lastline.'yank a'
  " Change to do what you need with register a.
  " Insert output before a:firstline
  exec (a:firstline - 1).'read !your magic with '.@a
  " Restore the register
  let @a = old_reg
endfunction

" :2,5MyOwn  will process lines from 2 to 5 and insert the output before line 2
command! -bar -range -nargs=? MyOwn <line1>,<line2>call MyFunc()
```